# Mule-splitting URL parameter

Tags: java, mule

I need to split the Parameters using Mule. Suppose the url is : http://localhost/study/mystudy/class?classname=bla-bla

If I do `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path']` It returns `/study/mystudy/class`. Now I need to find a way to get each of these parameters i.e. **study,mystudy,and class** and keep it into an array.

I can do it by using Java Custom Transformers but it will be the last option. Please help me if there is something in mule to do this.

Comment: You can try using Groovy script in Mule.

Comment: @RamakrishnaN New to mule. Any help from you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEL(Mule Expression Language) allows you to use Java method invocation so you can use simple String methods for this:

```
<set-payload value="#[Arrays.asList(message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path'.replaceFirst('^/', '').split('/'))]" />
```

Or alternatively you could also use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.split which might be a bit cleaner.